# Making your Query String look nicer

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my url :

```
items.php?category=all&page=2
```

Into :

```
items/all/2
```

I understand that I am able to do this using mod_rewrite. What i want to know is after using mod_rewrite, am i able to use

```
<a href="items/all/2">
```

or do i still have to use

```
<a href="items.php?category=all&page=2">
```

I want to be able to use the first one. If it can't be done using mod_rewrite, what other ways can I achieve this result?

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite for this and after that you can use string like this `<a href="items/all/2">` in your code, try using below rule.

Note that it is rewriting not redirecting so your link above will processed as `<a href="items.php?category=all&page=2">` inside apache.

Put below rule in `.htaccess` file inside your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)\([\w]+)\([\w]+)$ $1.php?category=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

Indeed to get nicer looking URLs, you can use **mod_rewrite**. Using this kind of rule in your `.HTACCESS` file:

```
RewriteRule ^voitures/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /vehicules.php?gamme=$1 [L]
```

Allows you to access `example.com/vehicules.php?gamme=xyz` via `example.com/voitures/xyz`